# Binding to a List with Lightswtich

Tags: silverlight, binding, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch app which creates a series of survey questions, with answers.  I have 2 `datagrids`, 1 for the questions and 1 for the answers.  When the selected item in Questions changes, the `datagrid` for the answers updates.  I'd like to be able to preview what the data looks like for each question individually in my Silverlight control.

I'm binding the question property to the `Screen.SurveyQuestions.SelectedItem.Question`.  Now I'm not sure how to grab the answers.  If I bind my `List<string>` to `Screen.SurveyAnswers`, I get `null` every time, though I know there is data there.  Since `SurveyAnswers` is a complex object, I have a method that just pulls the Answer string and stores it in a list, which I have also tried binding too.  This works...the first time only.

Is there a way to `RaisePropertyChanged` or to break the binding and rebind?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I am a newby, but hope you will be more happy with my answer then with none :)

I would try to create new Query for the answers grid (if you don't have any yet) and then i would set a parameter for that answers query which would be bound to selected Question object (or to some of its properties). Query designed like that should keep en eye on a parametr change, so it should refresh the answers view.

Hope I ain't wrong and that it helps.